# Building Macro from Parts

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, avr

I'm working on a an AVR, and the libraries include device interrupt vectors like `TCD0_OVF_vect` and `TCD0_CCA_vect` using preprocessor `#defines` as follows:

```
#define TCD0_OVF_vect_num  77
#define TCD0_OVF_vect      _VECTOR(77)  /* Overflow Interrupt */
```

They also include timer objects:

```
typedef struct TC0_struct
{
  register8_t CTRLA;  /* Control  Register A */
  ...snip...
} TC0_t;

#define TCD0    (*(TC0_t *) 0x0900)  /* 16-bit Timer/Counter 0 */
```

I want to be able to define a macro that will expand a named timer object, `TCD0`, to `TCD0_OVF_vect` using a syntax similar to `VECT(TCD0, OVF_vect)`. For example:

```
ISR(VECT(TCD0, CCA_vect)) {}
```

converts to

```
ISR(TCD0_CCA_vect) {}
```

where `TCD0_CCA_vect` is a macro that needs to be expanded.

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:**
In addition, I would *love* to be able to do:

```
#define TIMER TCD0
#define VECT(a, b) ##SOMETHING##
```

and then be able to use `VECT(TIMER, CCA_vect)` and end up with `TCD0_CCA_vect`. I know this requires another level of indirection, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite easy:

```
#define VECT(a, b)  a##_##b
```

The `X##Y` will concatenate `X` and `Y` as a single identifier.

In your particular case, you need to concatenate `TCD0`, `_` and `CCA_vect` into a single identifier `TCD0_CCA_vect`.

Note that this won't work with variables!

Comment: I added an edit above. In short, is it possible to use `#define TIMER TCD0` and then use `VECT(TIMER, CCA_vect)`?

Comment: @CarsonDarling, unfortunately there's no way. Pasting tokens together (using `##`) happens before macro expansions, so you can't have the macro `VECT(a, b)` to first expand `a` (in your example `TIMER`) and then create a new token with `##`.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, especially since `TIMER` would need to be expanded once to `TCD0` but not all the way to `0x900`, then pasted together into `TCD0_CCA_vect`, and then expanded again. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @CarsonDarling, you are absolutely right. To help reduce repeated code, you may want to find a way to map `a` and `b` to the `a_b` constants with an array and some logic so you can loop over it or have `a` and `b` as variables.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job, using token concatenation.

```
#define VECT(a, b) a ## _ ## b
```

---

From a comment:

> Is it possible to use `#define TIMER TCD0` and then use `VECT(TIMER, CCA_vect)`?

Not directly, but with another level of macro, the answer would be yes:

```
#define TIMER TCD0
#define PVECT(a, b) a ## _ ## b
#define VECT(a, b)  PVECT(a, b)

VECT(TIMER, CCA_vect)
```

The output from that is:

```
TCD0_CCA_vect
```

The arguments passed to PVECT are expanded before being passed, which is why this works.